# Program to export Facebook chat to other format(s)

Tags: gratis, facebook, archiving

Background:
As many users of [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) have probably found (assuming they're like me) the chat history is ridiculously lame, annoying and inneffective for long conversations. I have one convo in particular that has over 14k messages including attachments/pictures. To view anything older than a week or two is a LOT of scrolling.

So what I'm looking for for this program to do:

- *Must* Gratis.
- *Must* Grab whole chat history of ***one*** message thread and save it in a different format.
- *Must* Saveable as *at least one* of these options:

  - "nice" html - something *like*: full width with H3s for each day, H2s for each week or month, skips profile image but include user name and post time.
  - as email archive (any standard email format) of one message per day or per chat message
  - something else easy to use and everything.
- *Bonus* Open Source.
- *Bonus* multiple destination format options.
- *Bonus* built in automation capable - like grab and append every x days (rather than scheduled task and wasting bandwidth etc of overwriting the whole thing)
- *Bonus* GUI to select list of message threads - each thread to a separate file or folder if in an mail box type format.
- CLI or GUI is fine
- Preferred a Windows app or Chrome/Firefox Extension/scriptlet.
- Acceptable Linux app
- a web-app is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has [an option](https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150292657680484) to download most of your Facebook data, including sent and received messages. Go to your Settings and click on  “Download Your Information” :

[image]

It is gratis, no app is required and it grabs your whole chat history. One issue is that you cannot select what you want to retrieve, so if you have 100 GB of videos I hope you have a decent connection.

The archive is in HTML, your messages are in `facebook-Francky/html/messages.htm` (replace Francky by your username). The `messages.htm` contains all your threads, ordered by the last message retrieved in the thread. Unfortunately, **files attached to messages are not present in the backup**. Well done Facebook...

Here is how the archive looks like:

[image]

Comment: I suppose I should have specified that I was aware of that option. However it doesn't work well for me for two reasons; which I should have specified as well. 1. All messages in one file (yes I can manually extract each set but that isn't nice) 2. no quick division between date ranges. (editing my question to specify those, thanks) - but a good answer even if it doesn't quite fit what I want (which of course may or may not exist)